# adding column Foreign key MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I create 2 table and i try add FOREIGN KEY to table on bottom picture. Tables look like

http://zapodaj.net/02b893dfd5982.png.html
 the top table name:"tabela_postow" the bottom name:"tabfile"

I try add column to tabfile with foreign key but all the time get         Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'heroku_fd1c348s48a7d8c.#sql-dd3f_ad2f19' (errno: 150)

I use this command.

ALTER TABLE tabfile
ADD column idpost mediumint(9) not null,
ADD FOREIGN KEY (idpost) REFERENCES tabela_postow(id);

Im new and really dont know why its not work.

Comment: Your command looks good.  What storage engine do the tables use?

Comment: I had 2 engine first one InnoDB   and secound is  'MyISAM'  thanks for helps problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can check the status of InnoDB (SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS)
The primary key's on the referenced tables  most likely  should be NOT NULL
```

So Create first table where column id should be like this `id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL primary key`
 or create index manualy `CREATE INDEX ix_id ON table_name (id)`

Comment: `tabela_postow.id` is already defined as `id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL primary key`.

Comment: then you should try to create index manualy CREATE INDEX ix_id ON table_name  (id);

Comment: I had 2 engine first one InnoDB   and secound is  'MyISAM'  thanks for helps problem solved